# How to get element by id which is dynamically created by ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am only posting the necessary code and solving this much will clear rest of my doubts. I am new to angularjs, so kindly forgive if I am asking something stupid.

I am using ng-repeat to generate a list which uses an array defined in the controller scope. When I click on 'Add Another' button, a new element is created. I want to get access of this element to add a class to it. But when I use 'getElementById' function in the same function 'addNewForm' I get 'null'.
However, when I call function 'fn' by hitting 'Find Untitled' button, I get the correct element. Could anybody explain and solve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I am posting the code below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl3">
    <ul id ="menu_Ul">
        <li ng-repeat="x in list">
            <button id="{{ 'navAppsButtonID-' + $index }}">{{x}}</button>
            <br>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button ng-click="addNewForm()">Add another</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="fn()">Find Untitled</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.controller("myctrl3", function($scope) {
          var list = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop'];
          $scope.list = list;
          $scope.abc = function () {
            var listPush = function () {
              $scope.list.push("Untitled Menu");
              for(var i = 0;i<$scope.list.length-1;i++) {
                var element = document.getElementById('navAppsButtonID-'+i);
                element.classList.remove('current');
              }

            };
            var listLen = $scope.list.length;
            if($scope.list[listLen-1] === undefined) {
              listPush();
            }
            else if ($scope.list[listLen-1] == "Untitled Menu") {
              alert("Cannot open more than one Untitled Menu at the same time.");
            }
            else {
              listPush();
            }
          };
          $scope.addNewForm = function() {
            $scope.abc();
            console.log("Element is: ", document.getElementById('navAppsButtonID-'+($scope.list.length-1)));
          };
          $scope.fn = function () {
            console.log("Element is: ", document.getElementById('navAppsButtonID-'+($scope.list.length-1)));
          };
        })
```

Comment: You don't use `getElementById` when you're using angular. You use some angular function to do what you need to do. You're thinking too much jQuery and too little angular. For example, all you really need is to add another element to `list`, then the template will re-render another `ng-repeat` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking too much jQuery and too little angular. If the goal is to add a class to the last element of `ng-repeat`, this is how you do that:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in list">
    <button ng-class="{ current: $last }">{{ x }}</button>
</li>
```

[`$last`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview) is a variable available inside [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), and if it's true, [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) will set the class `current` on the element.

You don't assign unique ids to elements to `getElementById` from somewhere else when working in angular.

Comment: Well, I dont always want to add class to the last element. I want to add the class to the newly created element that is pushed to the end of the list when user click 'Add another' button. If I try your solution then it'll always add the class to the last element no matter whether it is the 'Untitled Menu' (newly created element) or not.

Comment: Well then add some additional condition. I don’t know what your logic is, I’m just showing you the proper angular approach to the issue. `{ current: somethingsomething && $last }`